# IRC like WebApp Chat

Tags: web-apps, chat

I'm searching for open source webapp or SaaS project that will look like IRC in browser but with log history (and search). Those chats should be private. It can be very basic. I'm looking for something that will help programmers in a team to comnunicate.

Does something like this exist? I can't find anything like this. If there is no Open Source solution like this, maybe there is SaaS that provides this kind of Software, it can be free (as in beer) or not.

Comment: would IRC with a web client be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek IRC don't keep history there will be need for irc bot that will keep history. And since history is not handled by IRC the client will nto have access to it.

Comment: problem with private chats is that they require a ton of moderation. you can make one, it's not too hard with socket.io.

Comment: @KaranGoel I can make one, but wanted to know if there is already something like this.

Comment: there used to be something called `irc-cloud`, its something like mibbit but its invite only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PHP FREE CHAT](http://www.phpfreechat.net/)

[image: PHPFREECHAT LOGO]

You can use it to let your visitors discuss through public and private chat rooms. In addition, the interface is customizable on desktops, tablets and smartphones to fit your website design.

OPEN SOURCE VERSION

- Free version
- JQuery plugin client side
- PHP code server side
- Keep data on your server
- Deep customization
- Share with community
- Contribute to the code

[image: CHAT Window]

http://www.phpfreechat.net/download

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that there is [slack.com](http://slack.com) service (SaaS) it have very good free plan.

It give channels like IRC and allow to connect to services like Jira, github bitbucket which give additional functions. It have history of chat and search. when you register you will have url with subdomain and you can invite users.

**UPDATE** found also [lingr.com](http://lingr.com/) free public and private chat and [gitter.im](https://gitter.im) chat app (in beta) created specific for github projects (I think)

Answer (score 1):

Jabbr is an OpenSource ASP.net chat application.

https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR

It can be seen live here: https://jabbr.net/

Very nice is the feature that it keeps its history. So you can scroll back if you joined a conversation too late.